# Issue filtering array using criteria | Swift 5

Tags: arrays, swift

How can the following JSON array be filtered to exclude values `type` = `quiet` to only initiate viewcontrollers where `test.testid` type everything else.

**Currently doing the following:**

```
do {
  let nav = try JSONDecoder().decode([TestStruct].self, from: data)

  self.viewControllers = nav.map { test -> UIViewController in
    let selected = UIImage(named: "Tab4_Large")!
    let normal = UIImage(named: "Tab4_Large")!
    let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(test.testid))
    controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    controller.floatingTabItem = FloatingTabItem(selectedImage: selected, normalImage: normal)

return controller
}
```

**JSON Decode Structure:**

```
struct TestStruct: Decodable {
    let testname: String
    let type: String
    let testid: Int
}
```

Need to exclude type = "quiet", but include the rest in the `nav.map`

**Example JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "testname": "Teller",
    "type": "load",
    "testid": 2
  },
  {
    "testname": "Manager",
    "type": "load",
    "testid": 8
  },
  {
    "testname": "Tester",
    "type": "quiet",
    "testid": 8
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

For the result that you want to achieve. First need to filter the array with the values not having `type = quiet`.

```
let filteredArray = nav.filter { $0.type != "quiet" }
```

then you can use `compactMap` to get your desired result. I am not sure about the `instantiateViewController` part will work the way you want.

But I am adding a simple example which I tried in `Playground`:

```
var stringData = "[{\"testname\":\"Teller\",\"type\":\"load\",\"testid\":2},{\"testname\":\"Manager\",\"type\":\"load\",\"testid\":8},{\"testname\":\"Tester\",\"type\":\"quiet\",\"testid\":8}]"

let data = stringData.data(using: .utf8)!

struct TestStruct: Decodable {
    let testname: String
    let type: String
    let testid: Int
 }

struct ViewControl {
    let id: Int
}

do {
    let nav = try JSONDecoder().decode([TestStruct].self, from: data)
    let filteredArray = nav.filter { $0.type != "quiet" }
    print(filteredArray)
    let controllers = filteredArray.compactMap({ test -> ViewControl in
            let viewControl = ViewControl(id: test.testid)
            return viewControl
        })

    print(controllers)
 } catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: This is the right idea. Do one thing at a time: read the array from the JSON first, filter it to remove unwanted entries second.